# Not able to turn off auto-complete for ngx-otp-input in Angular

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I am not able to turn off the auto complete for OTP in ngx-otp-input.
I have already tried with

- autocomplete="off"
- autocomplete="new-password"
- By making a template variable and changing its property

```
 <ngx-otp-input #disableautocomplete class="mobile-otp-ui mobile-otp-ui-otp" id="otp-1" [config]="otpInputConfig2" (otpChange)="handleOtpChange2($event)" (fill)="handleFillEvent2($event)" name="mobileotp" autocomplete="off" >
  </ngx-otp-input>
```

```
 @ViewChild('disableautocomplete', { read: ElementRef }) disableautocomplete;
 ngAfterViewInit(){enter image description here
    this.disableautocomplete.nativeElement.autocomplete ='off';
  }
```

Comment: This isn't going to work since `ngx-otp-input` is simply a wrapper for the input elements. To iterate over the input elements you could follow for example [this approach](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2nre6c?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Can you try this out to see if it works?

Answer (score -1):

Just try using .
Here is the code am using

```
<ng-otp-input #ngMobileOtpInput id="otp" (onInputChange)="onOtpChange($event)"
                                [config]=" {length:6,inputClass:'dot',allowNumbersOnly:true}">
                            </ng-otp-input>
```

Ts code

@ViewChild("ngMobileOtpInput") ngMobileOtpInputRef: any;